# Issue with installation of Mongo DB on Windows 8.1

Tags: mongodb, installation, windows-8.1

I am trying to install Mongo DB on a windows 8.1 64 bit machine and I a getting the following error.

C:\MongoDB\bin>mongo.exe

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.7
connecting to: test
Tue Nov 19 14:50:02.652 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src
/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed

Comment: have you tried to google for this error?

Comment: Yes...I mean Obviously...can you point me to some windows related links

Comment: It is like 5 links just by copying the text. Have tried any of them? If so what was the problem and why their solution was not working for you?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/ follow the guidance there. You need to install. MongoDB as a service or run from the command line before using the console.

Comment: Use this link. I also faced lot of problems when installing.But before found [this link. ](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-windows/)

Comment: pls correct the title typo?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the daemon process running.  You start it via mongod.exe.  You are running the client side and by default connecting to port 27017 - the default mongo instance.  Check your running processes for mongod first!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to unclick the download compass section when you download the shell. As soon as I unclicked it I was able to install the Mongodb shell. Hope this helps - I was stuck with this problem for a long time.